# How to set background and foreground color of QTableWidget row Vertical Header Item

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I am trying to set the background and foreground color of a `QTableWidgetItem` that is a Vertical Header Item in a row of my `QTableWidget`.  The following code does not work for a `QTableWidgetItem` that is a vertical header item, even though the same code works fine for a `QTableWidgetItem` that is a regular cell.

I'm using Qt 4.8 on Fedora 17 x64 Gnome 3.4

```
static const QBrush AddedCellBackground = Qt::yellow;
static const QBrush AddedCellForeground = Qt::red;

void rowSelected()
{
    QTableWidgetItem *vertHeadItem = _getSelectedItemVerticalHeader();
    vertHeadItem->setForeground( AddedCellForeground );
    vertHeadItem->setBackground( AddedCellBackground );
}
```

This code makes no change when `vertHeadItem` is a vertical header item, but it has the desired affect when it is a regular cell.  How can I set the background and foreground of a vertical header item?

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing forcing the `QStyle` in use to use the palette, colours can be hardcoded into the style itself.  It's hard to know without looking at the source code for it (`QGtkStyle` I think).

Comment: Would stylesheets work? See [this](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview) for an example.

Comment: @thuga I was able to get the stylesheets to change the BG, but I'm still trying to figure out how to make it apply to only certain rows

Comment: Still no dice.  I haven't been able to assign an object name to the vertical header item since they're not `QObject`s, thus I don't know how to do only certain rows.

Comment: Is this certain row a selected row or just any random row?

Comment: It is a row that has been "added" but not yet saved.  Essentially it needs to have a green background to indicate to the user that the row isn't saved to the database yet.  There could be any number of these rows, and any number of saved rows.  I can set the content cells but I still can't set the vertical header item

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If not I posted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily target specific items by knowing it's "AccessibleName", you can try this:

```
QTableWidgetItem#YourAccessibleName {

/* style definitions */

}
```

Comment: How can I get/set the AccessibleName?

Comment: It looks like non-`QObject`s cannot have Accessible Names

Answer (score 0):

In the question [Is it possible to change the colour of a QTableWidget row label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682474/is-it-possible-to-change-the-colour-of-a-qtablewidget-row-label) about the same topic but for PyQt my solution was to get the `QTableWidgetItem` of the vertical header and set the background and foreground there, however only the foreground was changed, the background stayed a smooth gray gradient. Probably the style was overridding/ignoring the background. Specifying a different style (Cleanlooks for example) fixed it.

So add something like in the construction of the table widget

```
QTableWidget::verticalHeader().setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("CleanLooks"))
```

Comment: Not sure about the syntax, not really familiar with C++ syntax.