# Is it possible to change the colour of a QTableWidget row label?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a class that inherits from QTableWidget and I'm wondering if it's possible to change the colour of the row label for each row in the table?

I don't want to change the colour of any of the cells or column headings.

Thanks :)

P.S. I would like each row label to have a different colour. The motivation is that I can use these colours as a key/legend as each row in the table corresponds to a differently coloured line on a plot.

EDIT: Image illustrating the elements of the table I am referring to:

[image: row labels highlighted in red]

Comment: It may be easy done with implementing custom `QStyledItemDelegate`, if you replace your `QTableWidge`t with `QTableView` + `QStandardItemModel`.

Comment: Thanks for your response - unfortunately I think I am stuck with using QTableWidget for now. Good to know for the future though!

Comment: I'm still not recommend you to use `QTableWidget`, because it has too pure customization widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible but only with a slight trick. With `setVerticalHeaderItem` of `QTableWidget` you can set a `QTableWidgetItem` even for header rows and there you can define a background brush for each row. However most of the times the background will be ignored because the actual `QStyle` will override it. Setting the style of the vertical header widget to a style that doesn't change the background however does the trick.

Example:

```
from PySide import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

table = QtGui.QTableWidget(4, 2)
table.show()

for i in range(0, 4):
    item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Text')
    item.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(i*50, i*30, 200-i*40))
    table.setVerticalHeaderItem(i, item)

# print(QtGui.QStyleFactory.keys())
table.verticalHeader().setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('CleanLooks'))

app.exec_()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it appears that you can do so, using the [QTableWidgetItem functions](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidgetItem.html#PySide.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem) such as setForeground which you pass through a [QBrush object](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QBrush.html#PySide.QtGui.QBrush) that I believe you can use the QBrush's setColor function to pass it a color. The QTableWidgetItem documentation has a lot of aesthetic-based functions so it looks like what you're looking for especially since it seems to be able to target specific cells/items on the table. If you want to look more into the QTableWidget documentation itself, here's [a link to that](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget.html) as well.

Comment: I believe this functionality relates to changing the properties of the actual _cells_, rather than the row labels. To clarify what I mean I have added an image to my question. Thanks for your time, but for now I don't believe this solves my problem.